# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: not firing as scheduled after app returns to foreground

Tags: ios

I am scheduling a selector using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: with a five minute delay.  If the device goes to sleep for more than five minutes while this is scheduled, then one of two things happens:

1)  If the device is connected to my laptop, and the app is running in the debugger, then when the app wakes back up the selector fires immediately.  It seems like the "clock keeps running" for the delay.

2)  If the device is not connected, then there is a delay before the selector fires.  It seems like the "clock pauses" for the delayed selector.

It seems strange that there would be two different behaviors depending on whether the device is connected to the debugger or not.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the debugger seems to force the app alive in the background.

Typically, if you are debugging on a real device and press the home button, nothing special will happen, even after 10 minutes.

On the other hand, if you force kill your app on the device, you'll end up receiving a SIGKILL signal which will terminate your debug session.

Answer (score 0):

The app is paused, when in background. You should generally save timers etc, in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and restart them in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.